# Hide the `prototype` property from override native function by custom function

Tags: javascript

when native method customized by js function  like that

```
console.log = function myLog(args){...}
```

or using `Object.definePropery(...)`
then

```
'prototype' in console.log == true
```

Are there is a way to hide the `prototype` key so it feel more like native function ?

so

```
'prototype' in console.log == false
```

Comment: No. JavaScript properties are always public.

Comment: I thinks you answer to much quickly ...

Comment: What do you mean by "*feel more like native function*", what is your goal? Normally nobody is bothered by a `.prototype` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>You could delete the property:</s>

```
console.log = function myLog(args){…};
delete console.log.prototype;
```

Alternatively, create a function that doesn't have a `.prototype` in the first place by not using a function expression:

```
console.log = {log(args) {…}}.log;
```

```
console.log = (args) => {…};
```

Comment: I can't delete the propery but the other solution are very good. I wonder if there is way to do that without ec6

Comment: @perymimon Oops, you're right, the `.prototype` is non-configurable

Answer (score -1):

GetOffMyLawn is correct.  Object prototype is frozen

```
> Object
[Function: Object]
> Object.prototype
{}
> Object.prototype = null;
null
> Object.prototype
{}
```

As would be Function

```
> Function instanceof Object
true
> Function.prototype
[Function]
> Function.prototype = null;
null
> Function.prototype
[Function]
```

In order to re-assign a prototype you'll need to instantiate your own Object.  I think by default new Objects will not have any frozen properties, including prototype.

```
> function Test() {}
undefined
> const test = new Test();
undefined
> test
Test {}
> test.prototype
undefined
> test.prototype = null
null
> test instanceof Function
false
> test instanceof Object
true
> test instanceof Test
true
> test.prototype
null
> Object.prototype = test.prototype
null
> Object.prototype
{}
> Object.prototype.whoo = 'whoo';
'whoo'
> Object.prototype
{ whoo: 'whoo' }
> test.prototype = Object.prototype
{ whoo: 'whoo' }
> test.prototype
{ whoo: 'whoo' }
```

By design Object.prototype is not writable, enumerable or configurable (frozen).  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype

Comment: That's not what the OP was asking about at all